# Is it possible to move the media folder and its contents to a different server

Tags: magento-1.9, media

I want my media folder to be placed in another server
My server has low space. 
So I need it to be placed in another server.
Changing the media Url is not working.
Somebody suggest some idea

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to use a remote service in order to do that. I suggest you install a Magento ImageCDN plugin - https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/imagecdn.html

With this you can use one of the third party providers such as Amazon S3, or an FTP connection to a remote server.

You would need to setup Apache/Nginx on the server and have it serve those images eg media.yourdomain.com on http and https.